# Is it bad to let CSS3 infinite animations running, and leave the page. Is the animation still running invisibly?

Tags: css, background-process, hardware-acceleration

I've read somewhere, (unfortunately I can't find my source again) that if a user has loaded an HTML page with a running CSS3 animation (infinite parameter) and he decides to leave it, the browser (computer) still needlessly plays the animation and so, CPU (or Acceleration hardware?) is still working for the animation although the user left the page.

So if someone could answer me, I will be pleased.

Is this fact true?

And if it's true:

1. Are the transitions also concerned with this issue ?
2. Is pausing animation (and transition if concerned) enough to avoid this problem? (I was thinking to force the pausing with an `onbeforeunload` event) Or should I have to do another thing ? Notice that I don't want to use "hover" to start the animations/transitions.

PS: I'm still new in CSS, javascript and know no other language. And sorry but my knowledge of English language is far from top...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user leaves the page completely (e.g. navigates to a whole new page or closes that tab) then the animations shouldn't keep running. If they somehow do keep being updated, it's because of a browser bug and you shouldn't worry about it anyway.

However, CSS3 animations for hidden elements (`display: none;`, for instance) still get evaluated, since they are keyframe-based, and there might be a keyframe sometime in the future that would cause the element to become visible again.

Imagine wanting to animate a box by first hiding it, then showing it again and making it flash. If CSS transitions would suddenly become disabled when the box is hidden, the animation would stop and the box would never appear again. And that's not what you want.

Note: profiling your web page can be done e.g. in Chrome using the Developer Tools (F12 -> Profiles). I haven't used it to profile CSS3 animations though, so I'm not sure if it can be done. You can however just take a look at Chrome's very own task manager (`Shift-ESC`) and see whether your website is using up a considerable amount of CPU. If that's true, then it's a sign that there might be too many animations on that page.

Comment: Thanks for your explainations Andrei. So I probably missunderstood what I've read bofore and that's better ! I was asking this because when I was adjusting color animations among multiple 25px radius spots, and loading and loading again the page to choose the better effects I wanted, the browser (chrome) was at the end very very slowdown, nearly freezed I'd say. So I add a pause button that I used before every reload, and it seemed to solve the problem. Now you teached me that the problem had its origin elsewhere. Thanks !

Comment: I know that CSS3 animations, especially for large elements, are currently quite slow on most computers. There's still a lot of work being done in that direction by the browser developers. I actually remember creating a simple, almost blank web page with just a scrolling background (400x400px, tiled). The animation was done with CSS3 and only that single animation (which was actually animating the whole background, but still), used up around 20% of my CPU.

Comment: OK ! Underneath my 50 color changing spots, I have a 920x150px animated gradient box. That can explain !

Comment: (Sorry typed enter key too rapidly). Is is easy to see the amount of CPU that a page is using ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer (Shift-ESC in Chrome brings up Chrome's Task Manager). I'm not sure about actual CSS3 animation profiling tools though.

Comment: Thanks I learned one more thing today ! Well, reloadind many many times the same page with my unpaused animations, doesn't affect the number in the UC column. It still goes around 40 (I don't know wich unit)... Opening many times the same page doesn't seem to affect this number wich is only present for the active tab. Inactive tabs are oscillating between 1 an 5. So it seems to be very well managed. However, I won't forget to look at this tool, the next time I'll observe strange browser behaviour. Many Thanks Andrei !

Comment: No problem ^_^. And I think it's just % of the total CPU used.